# Return all individual items from a combobox (non ActiveX) to a range of cells

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I want to return all items in a combobox to a range of cells in a sheet, without having to click on the combobox and select every single item in it. Can this be done? The code below is returning only the selected value in the dropdown

```
Sub drop_fetch()

Dim x As Integer
Dim nxt As Integer

nxt = Sheets("List").Range("F1").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Populate Cells in Sheet with items in the combobox named "Drop"

For x = 1 To 10
    Sheets("List").Cells(nxt, 2).Value = Sheets("Selection By Market").DropDowns("Drop").List(Sheets("Selection By Market").DropDowns("Drop").ListIndex)
    nxt = nxt + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are repeating the same thing 10 times.  Where does `x` come in?  Also, why use `nxt`?  It is always going to start at 2 if you start in row 1 and try to go up.

Comment: Yes. I want to set the ListIndex, so that it loops 10 times. Otherwise, it's returning the value for ListIndex = 1(or whatever is selected in the drop-down) 10 times, but can't seem to be able to do that

Comment: Never mind. Solved it.